# How do I import SimMetrics to Android Studio project?

Tags: android, gradle

I want use [SimMetrics](https://github.com/mpkorstanje/simmetrics) in my app. I'm using Android Studio 2.2.2 with Gradle 2.2.2. I added this lines into my **module** `build.gradle`

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile group: 'com.github.mpkorstanje', name: 'simmetrics', version: '4.1.1'
}
```

And into my **project** `build.gradle` I added

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2'
        //need this for ButterKnife
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}
```

Gradle sync successed, but I can't `import` anything from SimMetric, build just failes with `error: package org.simmetrics does not exist`.

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your depedencies section `simmetrics` should be `simmetrics-core`. The simmetrics artifact is just the master pom.

```
dependencies {
     compile group: 'com.github.mpkorstanje', name: 'simmetrics-core', version: '4.1.1' 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think likely you need to move it to the module gradle file.

Your project gradle file (or parent file if you're coming from maven language) should have

```
buildscript{
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

I'm not super up on my gradle but you may need an allProjects block in your project gradle file.

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

and then in your module gradle file

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.github.mpkorstanje:simmetrics:3.0.1'
}
```

Comment: Done. But no any effect (

Comment: See the above edit you might need an allprojects block it's kind of hard to say without seeing your overall project structure. Also in Android Studio I would make sure you do a clean and rebuild from the Build menu. To make sure everything is being refreshed.

Comment: Actually I almost a newbie with gradle. I added `allprojects` too, but it could not helped. I suggest, what I got wrong path (com.github.mpkorstanje:simmetrics), not only project configuration.

Comment: Also looking at maven central is has the version number as 4.1.1 is there any reason you are using 3.0.1 which appears to be an old version. Maybe the methods you are trying to use aren't in that old version.

Comment: Thank you for version fix!  But my problem is still here, I can't import anything from package `org.simmetrics`.

Comment: Could you update the question to include your full build.gradle files.

Answer (score 0):

I've given up and downloaded a *.jar from [here](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Csimmetrics) and placed it in `MyProject/MyModule/libs`. I reverted old changes in `build.gradle` files and added this lines to module `build.gradle`

```
repositories {
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile name: 'simmetrics-core-4.1.1' 
}
```